# Is it possible to build docker tags automatically?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I would like to version the docker image on each commit into master or whenever I create a new git tag. Is it possible using their automated Docker registry? So far I could find only building on specific branches but I couldn't find any way to tell DockerHub to create a new docker tag whenever I push a new git tag

Answer (score 0):

[drone](https://github.com/drone/drone) is continuous intergration tool. I think that if you use drone you can do it that you said in question.

First, You have to install drone.

ref: https://github.com/drone/drone#installation

Second, setting drone and start it.
github(or bitbuckit), and etc...

ref: https://github.com/drone/drone#setup

Third, create the `.drone.yml`

ref

- https://github.com/drone/drone#build-configuration
- http://drone.readthedocs.org/en/latest/publish.html#docker

Fourth, Enable commit hook in `http://localhost:8000/`

Then

drone will automatically build and push docker registry.

Good luck.

Comment: I see... it's a shame that I need a CI when the docker registry could provide a hook for tags as well.